# Sort a given string in ascending order

Tags: java, algorithm, programming-challenge, sorting, complexity

This code sort the string below in ascending order.

I'd prefer it split-up in two or three smaller, simpler methods. I'm also wondering whether my algorithm has a decent time complexity.

> **Given string**
>
> [H, B, D, G, F, E, A, C]
>
> **Output**
>
> [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H]

```
public class sortArray {
    public static void sort (String[] str)
    {
        int lastPos = str.length - 1;
        int minPos = 0;
        String s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < lastPos; i++)
        {
            minPos = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j <= lastPos; j++)
                if (str[j].compareTo (str[minPos]) < 0)
                    minPos = j;
            if (minPos != i)
            {
                s = str[i];
                str[i] = str[minPos];
                str[minPos] = s;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] str = {"H", "B", "D", "G","F", "E", "A", "C"};
        sort(str);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(str));
    }
}
```

Comment: In case if you are trying to sort an array, you could have achieve this whole thing with `Arrays.sort(str);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your algorithm is selection sort.

Selection sort has a time complexity of \$O(n^2)\$. For sorting algorithms, that's pretty slow.

Consider looking up a sorting algorithm such as quicksort, which, whilst it does have a worst case performance of \$O(n^2)\$, on average, it tends to take \$O(n log n)\$.

Or, as suggested in the comments, make use of the built-in libraries. Use `Arrays.sort`. Use of library code, especially when part of the language that you're programming in, can save significantly on the work you need to do.

---

Splitting up your code into several methods can be done.

Take this section, for instance.

```
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= lastPos; j++)
            if (str[j].compareTo (str[minPos]) < 0)
                minPos = j;
```

What it does is it looks for the smallest string in the array. So you could turn this into a function, with arguments for the array and the starting position (`array.length` will get you the end).

The swap,

```
        if (minPos != i)
        {
            s = str[i];
            str[i] = str[minPos];
            str[minPos] = s;
        }
```

Could also be a separate method.

If you extract those two sections of code to separate functions, the main sorting function will look like this:

```
public static void sort (String[] str)
{
    int lastPos = str.length - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < lastPos; i++)
    {
        swap(str, i, findSmallest(str, i));
    }
}
```